# Metaprogramming via macro

Tags: c++, c

I’d like to do the same stuff we can do with D’s mixins with C/C++ preprocessor. I’d like to write a function to generate a parameter list. For instance:

```
#define MK_FN_FOO(n,t) …

MK_FN_FOO(3,float)

/* it will expand into */
void foo(float x0, float x1, float x2) {
    /* do something else here */
}
```

I have some idea but I’m facing an issue. I have to do recursion and I have no idea how I could do such a thing:

```
#define MK_FOO(n,t) void foo(MK_FOO_PLIST(n-1,t)) { }
#define MK_FOO_PLIST(n,t) t xn, MK_FOO_PLIST(n-1,t) /* how stop that?! */
```

Comment: yeah sorry for the typo

Comment: can't you set up a `foo` with a container of floats?

Comment: @stefan, no I can’t I have to pass those arguments so low-level API functions I need to infer regarding the parameters

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write your `D` code in `D`? What specific C++ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkB, yes, I have to keep writing in C++ for obscure reasons (executable size for instance, I’m a demoscener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boost libraries have a vast extensive metaprogramming and everything else preprocessor library. It is possible to do this kind of thing using their utility preprocessor directives which will be much easier than doing it yourself, although still slightly confusing :)

I suggest you start there:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_Preprocessor

Edit: Here is another tutorial about them:
[Boost.Preprocessor - Tutorial](http://www-spires.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/doc/workbook_backup_010108/examples/ex1/workdir/PARENT/boost/libs/preprocessor/doc/tutorial.htm)

Comment: thank you! I’m reading this, but I’d like to understand the fundamental things behind it! :)

Comment: I think a better way round might be to try and understand how to use the boost libraries. Then look at the implementation of individual macros from the boost libraries, as all the source code is available! (It would be hard to use them if it wasn't)

Comment: That said, their implementation is probably over the top for understanding. There are certain preprocessor tricks that need to be used, but I would ask here or search when you come across those, rather than trying to find an overarcing solution.

Comment: I’m reading a paper about a trick with concatenation… really tricky :D

Comment: @skp: you should really check out [`repeat.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp) they have a huge list of BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_X to fake recursion and stop it at 0. Conclusion: use boost and forget about the internals.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked out the boost implementation in [`/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp) and for your example it would boil down to something like this:

```
#define MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_0(t)
#define MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_1(t) MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_0(t)  t x0
#define MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_2(t) MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_1(t), t x1
#define MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_3(t) MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_2(t), t x2
#define MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_4(t) MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_3(t), t x3
// etc... boost does this up to 256

#define MK_FN_FOO(n, t) void foo(MK_FN_FOO_REPEAT_ ## n(t))

MK_FN_FOO(3, float) // will generate: void foo(float x0, float x1, float x2)
{
}
```

Comment: yeah I got that too, now the body… harder! thank you anyway :)

Comment: I knew you would get it, just wanted to add it so I don't have to look it up again in future :)